# Fail to decode mongo document ID onto struct field

Tags: mongodb, go, struct, decode

Trying to use [mongo go driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver) to decode a fetch a single user document and decode it into a struct, using the [findOne](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver#usage) method. But, I am unable to decode the document ID on the struct field. I tried looking for it in their examples, or at other sites/blogs, but no luck. I am working with:

- go v1.13.4
- mongo v4.2.1
- mongo-go-driver v1.1.3

Below is the code snippet:

```
type User struct {
    ID            interface{} `json:"_id"`
    Name          string
    Email         string
    Password      string // hashed
}

/* Other versions of User struct which I already tried

type User struct {
    ID            interface{}
    Name          string
    Email         string
    Password      string // hashed
}

type User struct {
    ID            string `json:"_id"`
    Name          string
    Email         string
    Password      string // hashed
}

type User struct {
    ID            string
    Name          string
    Email         string
    Password      string // hashed
}
*/

func main() {
    conn := service.MongoConn() // get a mongo connection on the required database
    user := &service.User{}
    err := conn.Collection("users").
             FindOne(context.Background(), bson.M{"email": "foo@bar.com"}).
             Decode(user)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", user)
}
```

I want to use doc ID as a reference in other documents in a different collection, otherwise, I have to resort to some other unique field like email.

Comment: Have you tried tagging the field with bson:"_id" instead of json:"_id"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the struct should be like this:

```golang
import "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"

type User struct {
    ID primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id"`
    ...
}
```

to transfer your `_id` to string please use `xx.ID.Hex()`

> [see more on Github](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/master/bson/primitive/objectid.go)